# Where can I access Gdx.files.local()?

Tags: java, json, libgdx

I have a pre-made json file that I want to test out.
This Json file will be modified so I want to read/write.
I noticed that internal is read-only. So I want to save my Json file in the local storage(manually through eclipse or OS(windows 8)) such that I can access through files.local(). Does anyone know the address of the local storage defined by libgdx? So that I can save my pre-made Json file?

This is for testing only! 
If there is a better way for me to test out my json file (read/write) please help me!

Thank you!

Comment: It depends on the plattform (desktop, android etc.), but the table under this link (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling) point `
File (Storage) Types` should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the backend or plattform. This [link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling) should help, under the point 
`File (Storage) Types` you can see where they are stored on the different plattforms.
Also you can query the root path by using `Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath();`

Hope it helps.